# What is the most accurate way to make a digital copy of a DVD?

Tags: video, dvd, archive, video-conversion, brasero

I'm interested in making accurate, future-proof digital copies of some family movies which are on DVD. What is the recommended way of doing this in 2019?

I am inclined to think that it would be best to image the discs, but there are many formats to choose from: ISO, cdrdao, etc. I have also read that some programs take more care than others to make accurate copies.

Which program and format do you recommend for making accurate, future-proof digital copies of these DVDs?

Comment: Something like this might be enough: http://www.andrews-corner.org/linux/burning.html#movies Bear in mind that Ubuntu uses `genisoimage` instead of `mkisofs` but I believe that the syntax is the same...

Answer (score 0):

I have had excellent results using Brasero.

I use DVD-RWs.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean copying one disc to another? I'm interested in making a digital copy of a disc.

Comment: @John Karahalis Yes. I looked up digital copy and it's a bit ambigious as to what it is.